# Dynamic Path for Opening Files in an iterative process - Python

Tags: python, os.path

Looking for some helpful tips. I am trying to read through multiple .txt files present in a folder and its sub-folders and then use regular expression to extract phone numbers from them. I am able to do that using a for loop on os.walk. But when I try to read individual files in a nested loop, it keeps on throwing one error after another. Basically what i learnt so far is that it may not be opening the file as it is not finding it in the same directory and the path needs to be dynamic. I tried using {folder\subfolder\f} but didn't work, also tried os.path.join but to no avail. Any help is really appreciated.

'''

```
import re
import os
lst = []
for folder, subfolder, files in os.walk(top):
    for f in files:
        lst.append(re.findall(r'\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}', open(f, 'r+', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore').read()))
return lst
```

'''

Resulting error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-6932d4b1e2e1> in <module>
      4 for folder, subfolder, files in os.walk(top):
      5     for f in files:
----> 6         lst.append(re.findall(r'\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}', open(f, 'r+', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore').read()))
      7 return lst

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Instructions.txt'
```

Comment: What is your current working directory? `print(os.getcwd())`. It might be that you get the file name but you are in a different working directory to the one that contains `Instructions.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't join `subfolder` in the path since that is a list of subfolders in the actual folder you are walking through.

You should join `folder` and the file name from `files`:

```py
open(os.path.join(folder, f), 'r+', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore').read()))
```